# Balanced Zero-One Encoding

Tags: string, code-challenge, balanced-string, encoding

## Task

Encode a string that entirely consists of uppercase alphabets (`A-Z`) using only zeros and ones, using your own favorite scheme. But the rule isn't that simple!

## Rules

1. Your program/function must correctly handle any valid input string of **length 8**.
2. The results must have the same length for all inputs.
3. The results must be distinct for distinct inputs.
4. The results must be as short as possible.
5. The results must be zero-one balanced (have number of ones **similar** to that of zeros). They don't have to be equal (i.e. perfectly balanced), but your score will be penalized for that.

You don't have to provide a program/function that decodes your encoding.

## Input and Output

- You can decide to accept any set of 26 distinct **printable ASCII characters** instead of `A-Z`.
- You can decide to output any pair of distinct **printable ASCII characters** instead of `0` and `1`.
- You are **not allowed to output an integer** instead of a bit string, since it may have leading zeros and it's unclear if you actually met the rule 2.
- If you decide to deviate from the default (`A-Z` input and `01` output), you must specify the input/output character sets in your submission.

## Scoring

- Base score: Code size, or 1 if your program happens to be empty.
- Penalties

  - Penalty for length: multiply `1.5 ** (encoded length - 42)`
  - There is no bonus for being shorter; 42 is the minimal length for a perfectly balanced encoding of 8-length strings with alphabet size 26.
  - Penalty for being unbalanced: multiply `2 ** max(abs(ones - zeros) for every valid input of length 8)`, where `ones` and `zeros` are the counts of 1 and 0 in each output, respectively.
  - Your submission must either show a worst-case example (input/output) or theoretical explanation on the penalty value.
- The lowest score wins.

## Example Submission

### Hypothetical esolang, 0 Bytes, Score 74733.8906

Here is a hypothetical esolang, where an empty program prints out all the ASCII codes of input's characters in binary.

For example, if you give `AAAAAAAA` as input, the program will print `1000001` 8 times in a row, i.e. `10000011000001100000110000011000001100000110000011000001`.

The input alphabet is chosen to be `CEFGIJKLMNQRSTUVXYZabcdefh`. This way, all of the chars are converted to seven digits in binary, and the zero-one counts differ only by one per char (they all have three 1's and four 0's or vice versa when converted to binary).

The output length is always 56, and the worst-case unbalance occurs on the inputs like `CCCCCCCC`, where zeros appear 8 more times than ones.

Therefore, the score of this submission is `1.5 ** (56 - 42) * 2 ** 8 == 74733.8906`.

Comment: Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14908/78410

Comment: can I use my hypothetical esolang in which the empty program accepts a number N in letter-encoded 26-ary and outputs the N-th possible 42-bit sequence of sum 21?

Comment: @ngn - does your hypothetical language meet [our accepted criteria](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/53748)? - EDIT ah input is always [A-Z] - I guess that's easy enough... :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan yeah, Balboolenc is transpiled to Python - the empty program does as described above, any other program remains intact :)

Comment: Can the code take really long to run? For example, I might iterate over all length-42 binary strings to find balanced ones.

Comment: @xnor It's fine as long as you can prove the score of your submission.

Comment: Can we output a list of ones and zeroes or does it have to be a string?

Comment: @Dennis List output is OK, as in any other challenges.

Comment: ```Penalty for length: multiply 1.5 ** (encoded length - 42)``` do you mean 1.5 ** max(encoded length - 42, 0)?

Comment: The whole question is lead into "mustn't have unbalance, must be in 42 digits, who care real running time"

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
2Ḷx21Œ!Q
O_65ḅ26ị¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//MuG4tngyMcWSIVEKT182NeG4hTI24buLwqL///9HSFFJRktTQQ)

-1 byte thanks to caird coinheringaahing

might remember to re-add the explanation since it was restructured for golfing

Comment: E x p l a n a t i o n?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit added

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//MuG4tngyMcWSIVEKT182NeG4hTI24buLwqL///9HSFFJRktTQQ) by restructuring

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 bytes, 0 penalty, Score 11

This program uses `[0-9A-P]` for input and `[01]` for output.

```
ö■▄←·ï↨≡⌐╠H
```

[Run and debug it online](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%B6%E2%96%A0%E2%96%84%E2%86%90%C2%B7%C3%AF%E2%86%A8%E2%89%A1%E2%8C%90%E2%95%A0H&i=%2200000000%22%0A%2200000001%22%0A%220000000P%22%0A%2200000010%22%0A%220000ABCD%22%0A%22PPPPPPPP%22&m=2) - click the run button to start.  The first four test cases run in milliseconds.  The fifth in seconds.  The sixth in millenia.

The corresponding ascii representation of this program is this.

```
A$21*,26|bD|N
```

It leans heavily on the `|N` instruction, which gets the subsequent permutation of an array.

```
A$21*           "10" repeated 21 times
     ,26|b      get input and decode it as a base 26 number
          D|N    ... that many times get the next lexicographic permutation
```

All outputs are permutations of the initial string.  It has 21 zeroes and 21 ones.  Therefore, all outputs are 42 characters, and perfectly balanced.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 14 bytes, Max Diff: 0, Length: 64, Score: <s>149636.5528</s> <s>142154.7251</s> 104745.5869

```
sm@S.{.p*`T4xG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzjXIVivWq9AKyHEpML9/3@ljMz0/Jy01CIlAA)

Uses the lower case alphabet (`[a-z]`) instead of uppercase. Can use uppercase by replacing `G` with `rG1`, at the cost of 2 bytes.

I could have translated [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino)['s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157238/balanced-zero-one-encoding/157245#157245) for a better score, but frankly, I want an answer that actually works.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>779</s> 645 bytes, Max(Diff) = 0, Length = 48, Score = 7346.95

```python
def f(s):
 a,b=0,""
 for i in s:a=a*26+ord(i)-65
 a+=56*252**4
 for i in range(5):b=bin((int("4lnk28t9vtqgfrpfda9uyfrjhcjwjvno6aec2nwegi0g4mnublc05dher8fjm4s5gh55lu87a4itmc74t6tozcsfdbxkg82frwljy0wam1jht98g2j0bma021v5d48pwq0fklv0n1ltrxft1fpk5gt5mx5fj4p2mjqqpvcylt1xayxf1iwdmyoxgfvl7oui1oo6147bm9rqpqut9ns8hhjc77t3pqy48otovrsm1t4mmleumspkuef66ma1vi0l4mtkwaeeizuvvds9fro3vhc0mrn6ox17rdpk7xw747qf28934u5jci5q1qj81i7dyf7rf0x7hb19xm93xhxsgh4w8ifs6fhynsddbo9j938ewfvhjlbpiz50n5hanmno6c89blyx50e89z7vjq2ho2r2u2wwyu4q18kv4fi1nhmfbgjbnkdayr5kblaped4fo5u97bi9a67d89irxa0r9cinmnohfgjmh5fhkcr33",36)>>a%252*10)&1023)[2:].rjust(10,"0")+b;a/=252
 return b[2:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZLNjtsgAITveQrLUqs4u20Bg4FUWamv0aoHsI0BG7Ax/svLp1lpVe0cR5/mMPrGI@ng0ePRtCpT57m4njLxKm/gNc9PmQoxM5nx2XwVN3FB1UuIzdkU3yryxF5upLoggi4X/AmNwnftmRRXeZPGn8/Gp3OOB98jlviapk7FUTWCL4eKVtd2s6sPlWhr5Le2M6DDzi9yqAFpdBuZsg7PpNOEDAujApvkaopTlcK9nlUj975jSMVtsAfYhINWJ846ZIF0AiC4kgazcZuA6ocVeDikuKsE1diTLhG3E2XxiJydpnGtjyHBXRy7gmZr3BH2Tq0DDYuBIVQQU@l4nMZpSdzPTGtbU5rKcTowCymscXYwYeeGdnHz2C@tqion4GrAgF3qN9G25r6sazNzFUO56hq46KuwQxqbsaf7RjGdFGK8xAuxtSETnCyDhjaHolGBnWoJ@e54uet97jTemFFzpfTh56aRgVtesnZTq7aDHM2dAE@08O55b824HI6dgJbxO13thHRAES1o244FT5D1K1YGeu2U7Kz0fSOOSHo5iLFtsApk4VQaLiraMG7iLkDktXmf1qqzThOl@zqWZf5aVsXbm/jyrgUExVcIUFn8Qde/36Nd5nSGT7FAXrzIn@LH7QmdstimJfpMvkOPMT51eXqY//pIXpz@d78/khePfw)

The magic number 
`4lnk28t9vtqgfrpfda9uyfrjhcjwjvno6aec2nwegi0g4mnublc05dher8fjm4s5gh55lu87a4itmc74t6tozcsfdbxkg82frwljy0wam1jht98g2j0bma021v5d48pwq0fklv0n1ltrxft1fpk5gt5mx5fj4p2mjqqpvcylt1xayxf1iwdmyoxgfvl7oui1oo6147bm9rqpqut9ns8hhjc77t3pqy48otovrsm1t4mmleumspkuef66ma1vi0l4mtkwaeeizuvvds9fro3vhc0mrn6ox17rdpk7xw747qf28934u5jci5q1qj81i7dyf7rf0x7hb19xm93xhxsgh4w8ifs6fhynsddbo9j938ewfvhjlbpiz50n5hanmno6c89blyx50e89z7vjq2ho2r2u2wwyu4q18kv4fi1nhmfbgjbnkdayr5kblaped4fo5u97bi9a67d89irxa0r9cinmnohfgjmh5fhkcr33` (in base 36), or its decimal equivalent `382136276621246556626597379364678993894472503063952720559883124988542417847157286833446006767955087631166943136913765901237281892296575754126024183763829277879554548743231384272055945084065681774297483130020386641869860456147616177702938121538230311395513497506285733567467605871232294046704309941152721616618474501854355102646152223338484615876165254236449912858255665248186687952137487016925761633237335983620006273901509768720506129789443353730706676483647298576692613113269388239830925662977837917272690235355742330377154505179476767457756888107428475384947712227312747517748632498691058764154580934614231152483398774630508576533263098942260213967880819240793990219283490212843120923539516962682466148372296338428497778127570401190309339992457562121354271`,  encodes all 252 permutations of 5 `0`s and 5 `1`s.

The algorithm first converts `A-Z` into `0-25` and treat it as a base-26 number, then add `56*252**4`.

Then, the number is converted to a 5-digit base-252 number, and substitute with the corresponding permutation of 5 `0`s and 5 `1`s.

After that, delete the first 2 bits, which is guaranteed to be `01`. Then we have encoded the string to a 48-bit string, which consists of exactly 24 `0`s and 24 `1`s.

Comment: Pretty sure the penalties have to be multiplied (that is, your score is `7346.953125`).

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Oh I though it is addition ;P Edited

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 55 bytes, max diff 0, length 42, score <s>56</s> 55

This works but will take a long but doable time (`ZZZZZZZZ` took 2.5 days on my computer). Memory is no problem.

Uses `A-Z` as input and `1` and `A` as encoding characters. They are always perfectly balanced. Skips the first `26^7 = 8031810176` balanced combinations representing string shorter than 8 characters, but that's OK since there are `538257874440` available and I use `208827064575` and `208827064575 + 8031810176 < 538257874440`.

However it actually "counts" up to to the target combination which will take very long. That's why in the TIO link I only used a too short input string (which are also supported) to demonstrate that the output is correct. Will work up to a bit more than `AAAAAA` before TIO times out.`ZZZZZZZZ` should be about `26^3 = 17576` times slower.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$_=1x21 .($i=A)x21;s/(A*)(1*)1A/$2$1A1/ until"@F"eq$i++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqmCqZ2igZ2D9XyXe1rDCyFBBT0Ml09ZRE8i0LtbXcNTS1DDU0jR01FcxUjF0NNRXKM0rycxRcnBTSi1UydTW/v/f0cnZxfVffkFJZn5e8X/dgkQA)

The decoder is almost the same:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -ap
$_=1x21 .($\=A)x21;s/(A*)(1*)1A/$2$1A1/,$\++until"@F"eq$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqmCqZ2igZ2D9XyXe1rDCyFBBT0MlxtZRE8i0LtbXcNTS1DDU0jR01FcxUjF0NNTXUYnR1i7NK8nMUXJwU0otVImvrf7/3xAIHCHIEcGGsBxRwL/8gpLM/Lzi/7oFiQA)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES8), score 22186.623779296875

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>(i%2*127^c.charCodeAt()).toString(2).padStart(7,0))
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

For even length input, always outputs 3.5* of zeros and ones, so it only pays the 1.5 ** 14 penalty. Supported characters: `'+-.3569:<GKMNSUVYZ\cefijlqrtx`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
42ɠO%ḅ26ịœcH$ạ‘Ṭ
```

Uses `+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCD` for input and returns a list of ones and zeroes.

This attempts to build a list of 538,257,874,440 combinations in memory, so you'll need a large amount of RAM to run it as is...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//MTjJoE8lKzI0JOG4hTI24buLxZNjSCThuqHigJjhuaz//0RBRA) (testable; input length 3, output length 18)

#### How it works

```
42ɠO%ḅ26ịœcH$ạ‘Ṭ  Main link. No arguments.

42                Set the argument and the return value to 42.
  ɠ               Read one line from STDIN.
   O              Ordinal; map ['+', ..., 'D'] to [43, ..., 69].
    %             Take the code points modulo 42, mapping [43, ..., 69] to
                  [1, ..., 26].
     ḅ26          Convert the result from base 26 to integer.
            $     Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
           H          Halve; yield 21.
         œc           Generate all 21-combinations of [1, ..., 42].
                  There are 538,257,874,440 of these combinations. The first
                  269,128,937,220 begin with a 1.
        ị         Retrieve the combination at the index to the left.
                  [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26] in bijective base 26 equals
                  217,180,147,158 in decimal, so the retrieved combination will
                  begin with a 1.
              ‘   Increment; yield 43.
             ạ    Absolute difference; map [1, ..., 42] to [42, ..., 1].
                  The combination now begins with a 42.
               Ṭ  Untruth; turn the combination into a Boolean list, with 1's
                  at the specified indices and 0's elsewhere.
                  Since the maximum of the combination is 42, this list will have
                  exactly 42 items, 21 of which will be 1's.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>985</s> 135 bytes, Max Diff 0, Length 42, score 135

```python
lambda s:C(int(s,26),21,20)
B=lambda x,y:y<1or-~x*B(x+1,y-1)//y
def C(n,o,z):p=B(o,z);x=n>=p;return z+1and[x]+C(n-p*x,o-x,z-1+x)or[1]*o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc8xT8MwEAXgPb/iNvsSh9YuFJRiJBKgbHQPGYzSiCBqW3YqORn46wFDQbzpk@5JT2fH4dXo1dzJ5/ldHV5aBb6oaK8H6plYIxOciSUmpTxdAxuL8Zobl3@EtKQh42zMOS4WY9LuO6ioZoZNWFhZ0ohNkPpG2o3bD0enYcq40m0dmuyrmds0MJMHNuU8C2hczZvUzJ1x4KHXUJPlKYTBr3k0F6vzi/XlVfRtWd3dP2wfo3c/efrnHWmKBBRI6KjHBKyLzxFy9mZ6Tf3gvp8NiBB3Q9xV@NfzxwNVKKXgOH8C)

Courtesy of Bubbler

Ungolfed code:

```python
import math

def binomial(x, y):
    return math.factorial(x) // math.factorial(y) // math.factorial(x - y)

def string_to_int(input_str):
    result = 0
    for i in range(0,8):
        result += (ord(input_str[i])-65)%26 * pow(26,i)
    return result

def counting_function(target, ones, zeros):
    if zeros > 0:
        position = binomial(ones+zeros-1,zeros-1)
    else:
        position = 1
    if target > position:
        if ones > 0:
            print("1", end='')
            ones -= 1
            counting_function(target-position,ones,zeros)
    else:
        if zeros > 0:
            print("0", end='')
            zeros -= 1
            counting_function(target,ones,zeros)
        elif ones > 0:
            print("1", end='')
            ones -= 1
            counting_function(target,ones,zeros)

input_str = input("Input string (A-Z): ")
input_int = string_to_int(input_str)+1
target = input_int
ones = 21
zeros = 21
counting_function(target, ones, zeros)
print("")
```

Since other approaches seem quite inefficient, I've tried to make a time-optimal one. It is clealy O(N) in N bits of encoding, which is big-O optimal.

Hint: try to think of Pascal's triangle for this one ([this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#/media/File:Pascal%27s_triangle_pathways.svg) reveals it)

Sample outputs:

```python
Input:  AAAAAAAA
Output: 000000000000000000000111111111111111111111
```

```python
Input:  ZZZZZZZZ
Output: 011001000000011010011000111010110110111110
```

Execution time: < 0.013 s (roughly constant for all inputs)

Comment: [Here is a quick golfed version(135 bytes, score 135).](https://tio.run/##Tc8xT8MwEAXgPb/iNvsSh9YuFJRiJBKgbHQPGYzSiCBqW3YqORn46wFDQbzpk@5JT2fH4dXo1dzJ5/ldHV5aBb6oaK8H6plYIxOciSUmpTxdAxuL8Zobl3@EtKQh42zMOS4WY9LuO6ioZoZNWFhZ0ohNkPpG2o3bD0enYcq40m0dmuyrmds0MJMHNuU8C2hczZvUzJ1x4KHXUJPlKYTBr3k0F6vzi/XlVfRtWd3dP2wfo3c/efrnHWmKBBRI6KjHBKyLzxFy9mZ6Tf3gvp8NiBB3Q9xV@NfzxwNVKKXgOH8C "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Bubbler Incredible, I did not posses the skills to achieve this

Comment: But you should make some effort to minimize your score. All submissions should make a serious effort to optimize the score, otherwise it's invalid.

Comment: @user202729 I've modified to Bubbler's version then, which is minimized. I did make an effort to minimize my score though, just not through code size.

Comment: About the latter point... correct.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes, Max Diff 0, Length 42, Score 112

```python
lambda s:sorted({*permutations("01"*21)})[int(s,26)]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqji/qCQ1RaNaqyC1KLe0JLEkMz@vWEPJwFBJy8hQs1YzOjOvRKNYx8hMM5YrrSg/VyGzJLWoJD8/p1ghM7cAqFnrf0ERSE2aRmZeQWmJhqam5n83DxcXT38vNwA)

This only works in theory because of memory constraints. There are `538257874440` distinct balanced zero-one strings of length 42 and `208827064575` possible inputs, so some of the possible outputs will not be used.

-37 bytes thanks to @recursive

Comment: You could use `int(s,26)` for your index value rather than `sum(...)` if you change your input character set.

Comment: @recursive that would require unprintables. tried that already

Comment: Unprintables?  It uses `[0-9A-P]`, doesn't it?  On my machine, `int("123ABC",26) == 12855114`

Comment: @recursive oh yeah you're right idk what I was thinking lol. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 75 bytes, Max Diff 0, Length 42, score 75

```
0i:0(?v'A'-$dd+*+!
.")1+.\1+:0$:2%:}:@-2,@+$bl"
[ab+-?\$:?vv~3
~~]>n<v$-1<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDTykDDvkzdUV1XJSVFW0tbkUtPSdNQWy/GUNvKQMXKSNWq1spB10jHQVslKUeJKzoxSVvXPkbFyr6srM6Yq64u1i7PpkxF19DG7v9/RygAAA)

Fair warning, this will take a very *very* ***very*** long time to complete even for the trivial `AAAAAAAA` case. Runs through each binary representations of a counter until the (base 26 representation of the input)'th binary number with 21 `1`s is reached. If you want to test the program somewhat you can replace the `ab+` on the third line with `1` which will return the nth binary number with just a single `1`, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDTykDDvkzdUV1XJSVFW0tbkUtPSdNQWy/GUNvKQMXKSNWq1spB10jHQVslKUeJK9pQQUHXPkbFyr6srM6Yq64u1i7PpkxF19DG7v9/RwiIAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 146 Bytes, 42 maxlength, 0 unbalance, score 146

```
#include<algorithm>
long long i,s;int f(char*I,char*O){for(O[i=42]=s=0;i--;i<8?s=s*26+I[i]:0)O[i]=i%2|48;for(;s--;)std::next_permutation(O,O+42);}
```

Works for any continious 26 char, but warning it runs an unacceptable time

Comment: It looks like that you're requiring an empty array being passed in addition. I don't think that's valid. / If you are using GCC you can replace `#include<algorithm>` with `#import<regex>`.

Comment: I'll change it when GCC decide to stop using an given pointer as output

Comment: ... so that's pointer to output? Looks valid then. But you should mention the input/output format explicitly.